# Android share action. Trigger from navigation drawer rather than top bar.

Tags: android, share

My app has a navigation drawer and as one of its options on the left side I would like it to have "Share with friends". User can tap on Share with friends menu option and will trigger Android native Share action. Is it possible? Can you share with me a link on Tutorial or code sample on how to trigger Android Share action from other places like left side menu for example rather than top bar.

Thank you!﻿

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message to share");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "title"));
```

Comment: are we losing the benefits of the ShareActionProvider here? (if there's any)